# Sagt man "Ich spreche so wie das nicht"?

Tags: translation

If I want to say `I don't speak like this` do I say `Ich spreche so wie das nicht`?

Comment: I have some doubts, whether this phrase is unambiguous in English without more context. Does your voice sound different, would you choose different words, speak slower or what  else?

Comment: a) This question is very close to a translation request which is not well-received here. b) Your German sentence is inacceptable in any possible context c) For poper answering the question one would need more context: In what situation do you plan to use this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I don't speak like this.*

> **Ich** spreche so <s>wie das</s> *nicht*.

You don't need *wie das*, *like this* is all conveyed in *so* already.

> **So** spreche ich *nicht*.

The emphasis in German sentences is on the first element, then the last.